# how to display jquery numeric keypad inside a dialog box?

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a numeric keypad downloaded from the link .http://www.keith-wood.name/keypad.html.

Now I have a dialog box and I want to display the keypad when we click the text box inside the dialog box . Thanks in Advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#txtPassword').live('click', function (){
            alert("clicked");

         $('#txtPassword').keypad(); 
            });   
           });  
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first include jquery file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Download and include the jQuery Keypad CSS and JavaScript in the head section of your page.

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.keypad.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.keypad.js"></script>
```

then set this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#txtPassword').on('click', function (){// better use on at the place of live
    alert("clicked");

 $(this).keypad(); 
    });

});   

</script>
```

see **[DEMO IN FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/jTMwf/2/)**

Comment: Thanks Rituraj .. Now thw keypad is been displayed but when i click the keys its closing and not displaying on textbox

Comment: just wait let me check

Comment: Its a jquery plugin dialog box . Am able to  press the keys  if its a normal textbox but inside dialog box am not able to do

Comment: Thanks Rituraj. Can you create a dialog box and make numeric keypad to call . Do help me